# Atualizar estoque antes de salvar modelo com nested_attributes e gem cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Amigos, tenho um form que usa nested_attributes e uso o gem cocoon. Tenho 3 modelos envolvidos. Variation que contem o estoque, Order, que contém o pedido e é pai de Detail que contém o detalhe do pedido.

Está funcionando corretamente o salvamento, entretanto preciso atualizar cada o estoque de cada item antes de salvar.

Campos:

Details:

```
t.string   "order_id"
t.string   "cod_produto"
t.string   "desc_produto"
t.string   "cod_cor"
t.string   "desc_cor"
t.string   "desc_tamanho"
t.decimal  "preco"
t.integer  "quantidade"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.float    "total"
```

Orders:

```
t.string   "customer_id"
t.decimal  "valor_total"
t.integer  "item_total"
t.string   "order_num"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Variations:

```
create_table "variations", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "product_id"
  t.string   "size_id"
  t.string   "color_id"
  t.integer  "quantity"
  t.string   "barcode"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
do
```

Os modelos são:

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :customer

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['cod_produto'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :customer_id, :presence => true
  after_validation :sum_details
  after_create :set_order_num

  private

  def set_order_num
    update(order_num: "#{Date.current.year}-#{self.id}")
  end

  def sum_details
    total = 0
    qtd = 0
    self.details.each do |d|
      total += (d.quantidade * d.preco) if d.quantidade.present?
      qtd += d.quantidade if d.quantidade.present?
    end
    self.valor_total = total
    self.item_total = qtd
  end
end
```

detail.rb

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  after_validation :update_quantity

  before_save :get_quantity

  private

  def get_quantity
    @qtd = self.quantidade
  end

  def update_quantity
    if self.quantidade > 0
      self.quantidade = self.quantidade - @qtd
    end
  end
end
```

O que preciso fazer é: antes de salvar o modelo detail (lembrando que ele é um form filho do modelo order), preciso achar a quantidade de um produto que está no modelo variations e atualizar sua quantidade. Para isso tem que pegar no modelo detail o cod_produto + cod_cor + desc_tamanho e procurar pelo campo barcode no modelo variation para entao atualizar seu estoque. Estou usando o before_save para tentar pegar a quantidade mas nem isso está funcionando... Alguém poderia dar alguma luz ?

Obrigado

EDITADO: Inclusão dos controllers:

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
require "json"
def consulta_produto
  @variacao = Variation.find_by(barcode:params[:barcode])
  if @variacao.present?
     hash = {:cod_produto => @variacao.product.cod ,:desc_produto => @variacao.product.descricao,:cod_cor => @variacao.color.cod, :desc_cor => @variacao.color.descricao,:desc_tamanho => @variacao.size.descricao,:preco => @variacao.product.price }
     render :json => { :resultado => hash }
  else
    render :json => {:resultado => "error"}
  end
end
# GET /orders
# GET /orders.json
def index
  @orders = Order.all
end
# GET /orders/1
# GET /orders/1.json
def show
end
# GET /orders/new
def new
  @order = Order.new
end
# GET /orders/1/edit
def edit
end
# POST /orders
# POST /orders.json
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
# PATCH/PUT /orders/1
# PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @order.update(order_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
# DELETE /orders/1
# DELETE /orders/1.json
def destroy
@order.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :valor_total, :item_total, :order_num, details_attributes: [:id,:order_id, :cod_produto, :desc_produto, :cod_cor, :desc_cor, :desc_tamanho,:preco,:quantidade,:total, :_destroy])
end
end
```

details_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_detail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /details
# GET /details.json
def index
@details = Detail.all
end

# GET /details/1
# GET /details/1.json
def show
end

# GET /details/new
def new
@detail = Detail.new
end

# GET /details/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /details
# POST /details.json
def create
@detail = Detail.new(detail_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @detail.save
    format.html { redirect_to @detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @detail }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /details/1
# PATCH/PUT /details/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @detail.update(detail_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @detail }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /details/1
# DELETE /details/1.json
def destroy
@detail.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to details_url, notice: 'Detail was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_detail
  @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def detail_params
  params.require(:detail).permit(:order_id, :cod_produto, :desc_produto, :cod_cor, :desc_cor, :desc_tamanho, :preco, :quantidade)
end
```

variations_controller.rb

```
class VariationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_variation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# require 'barby/outputter/cairo_outputter'
# def barcode_output( order )
#       barcode_string = order.barcode
#       barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(barcode_string)

#       # PNG OUTPUT
#       data = barcode.to_image(height: 15, margin: 5).to_data_url
#     end
# GET /variations
# GET /variations.json
def export
@data = Variation.order(:created_at)
# @data = Variation.select(:barcode).order(created_at: :desc)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.csv { send_data @data.to_csv }
  end

end
def index

# @barcode = Barby::Code128B.new("160P10") rescue nil
# @outputter = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(@barcode)
# @blob = Barby::PngOutputter.new(@barcode).to_png #Raw PNG data

# @barcode = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new('160P10')
# @barcode_for_html = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(@barcode)
@variations = Variation.all
# @import = Variation::Import.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @variations}
end
# def import
#   @import = Variation::Import.new variation_import_params
#   if @import.save
#     redirect_to variations_path, notice: "Importados #{@import.imported_count} Cod Barras"
#   else
#     @variations = Variation.all
#     flash[:alert] = "Foram encontrados #{@import.errors.count} erros no CSV"
#     render action: index
#   end


# end
# require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
# blob = Barby::PngOutputter.new("12345").to_png #Raw PNG data
# File.open('barcode.png', 'wb'){|f| f.write blob }
#Convenience method
# File.open('barcode2.png', 'wb'){|f| f.write barcode.to_png }
# @barcode = Barby::EAN13.new('000000000')
# @barcode_for_html = Barby::CairoOutputter.new("0123456789")

# Variation.new.barcode       # => Barby::Code39 object
# Variation.new.barcode_data  # => <Barby::Code39 object>.to_png
end

# GET /variations/1
# GET /variations/1.json
def show
end

# GET /variations/new
def new
@variation = Variation.new
# @variacoes_js = Variation.joins(:color, :product, :size).includes(:color, :product, :size)
# # ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
# gon.variacoes = @variacoes_js.to_json
# @tamanhos = Size.order(:descricao).select(:id,:descricao)
# gon.tamanhos = @tamanhos.to_json
# @produtos = Product.order(:cod).select(:cod,:descricao)
# gon.produtos = @produtos.to_json

end

# GET /variations/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /variations
# POST /variations.json
def create
@variation = Variation.new(variation_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @variation.save
    format.html { redirect_to variations_path, notice: 'Variation was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @variation }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @variation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /variations/1
# PATCH/PUT /variations/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @variation.update(variation_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @variation, notice: 'Variation was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @variation }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @variation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /variations/1
# DELETE /variations/1.json
def destroy
@variation.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to variations_url, notice: 'Variation was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_variation
  @variation = Variation.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def variation_params
  params.require(:variation).permit(:product_id, :size_id, :color_id, :quantity, :barcode)
end
def variation_import_params
  params.require(:variation_import).permit(:file)

end
end
```

Comment: vc pode adicionar mais informações para facilitar a ajuda, por exemplo: **1)** qual o resultado da execução do seu código? (fica tudo 0?); **2)** como os parâmetros estão chegando no seu controller?

Comment: Inclui os controllers na pergunta. Quanto ao resultado ele simplesmente nao está entrando no before_save.Coloquei um ponto de debug la mas ele nao atinge. A forma como pensei em fazer mas nao sei como é pegar a quantidade de cada detail, buscar a variacao e atualizar a variacao com essa nova quantidade, somando ou subtraindo. caso a quantidade do detail > 0 entao eu diminuo no estoque (variation) caso <0 eu somo (pois houve devolucao). Como seria isso ?

Comment: uma dica é: se não está entrando no before_save então alguma está errada no controller e o objeto não está sendo salvo. Coloca um debugger no *create* do OrderController e veja se os parâmetros estão chegando corretamente

Comment: Sim os parametros estao ok no debugger do create. coloquei um debugger no before_save e no console tentei recuperar a quantidade, mas da erro:
(rdb:1) self.quantidade
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `quantidade' for ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::Before:Class

(rdb:1) self
ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::Before

Answer (score 1):

Te aconselho a criar um serviço que faça isso, caso contrário seu modelo ficará inundado de regras de negócio e não irá garantir confiabilidade nas transações.

Para esses casos em que uma ação irá envolver mais de 1 registro no banco de dados é fortemente recomendado que se crie **transactions**, que garantirá que as duas operações ocorram ou nenhuma.

Pesquisa um pouco sobre PORO, serviço, regras de negócio desacopladas do model, pode requerer um esforço extra no início, mas irá te livrar muita dor de cabeça no futuro.